# Duplicity 0.7.10 fails after upgrading librsync in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, python, dependencies, duplicity

I've spent a few hours trying to configure [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/index.html) to perform automated remote backups to a Google Drive.  At this point, it's safe to say that I'm in my own private dependency hell.

Using the version of Duplicity that came with my distribution (0.6.x), I was getting an error:

> BackendException: Google Docs backend requires Google Data APIs Python Client Library (see http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/).

despite the fact that I had the Google API Python Client installed.  So, I decided to try and upgrade duplicity, which failed with:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c duplicity/_librsyncmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/duplicity/_librsyncmodule.o
duplicity/_librsyncmodule.c:26:22: fatal error: librsync.h: No such file or directory
 #include <librsync.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So, I decided to try and upgrade `librsync` as well, to the latest stable version (2.0).  After struggling with dependencies for *that*, I finally got both `librsync` and `duplicity` updated to their latest stable versions.

So, when I went to give my upgraded version of Duplicity a spin using `duplicity --version`, I now get *this* error immediately:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/duplicity", line 71, in <module>
    from duplicity import collections
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 32, in <module>
    from duplicity import path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 43, in <module>
    from duplicity import librsync
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/librsync.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import _librsync
ImportError: librsync.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5):

To get `librsync.h` then

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev  
sudo apt-get install librsync-dev
```

work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by adding the path for the shared object `librsync.so.2` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  In Ubuntu, this has to be done using `ldconfig`:

`sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/librsync.so.2.conf`

**librsync.so.2.conf**:

```
/usr/local/lib
```

You must now reload Ubuntu's ldconfig cache:

`sudo ldconfig`

Answer (score 1):

Both pl.smith's and alexw's answers are correct here, but in combination. I received an identical error attempting to upgrade from duplicity 0.7.6 to 0.7.14 using pip on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Here's what I did to fix them:

1. Install the necessary librsync header files (these are not installed by default):

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install librsync-dev
   ```
2. Create a config file for librsync libraries in your ld cache directory (skip this step if the file already exists):

   ```
   sudo touch /etc/ld.so.conf.d/librsync.so.2.conf
   ```
3. Add the directory containing the librsync header files to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable:

   ```
   sudo <your favorite text editor> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/librsync.so.2.conf
   ```

   Add `/usr/local/lib` to a line in this file.
4. Refresh the `ldconfig` cache:

   ```
   sudo ldconfig
   ```